# Disable TCP Offload for CentOS 7 on laptop and VPS

Tags: centos7, tcp-offload-engine

I can disable outgoing and incoming TCP Offload on MACOS in user's `.bash_profile` file:

```
sudo sysctl net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_tx=0
sudo sysctl net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_rx=0
```

This stops the incessant Wireshark "TCP CHECKSUM INVALID" outgoing ipv4 packets. How do I do the same for CentOS 7?

I want the Wireshark reports only about the real invalid TCP Checksum packets. So I have checked the box under `Protocols->TCP` "Validate the TCP checksum if possible".

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the linux you should use the `ethtool` program.

For example, to disable only checksum offload you can run the `ethtool -K <iface> tx off rx off` command, where `<iface>` is the name of the corresponded interface.

Also, there are other offloads, those are enabled by default. So, if you'll see the huge packets in wireshark -  don't worry - it's some offload side effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for editing my question.